# Javascript how to convert \r \n line breaks in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript how to convert \r \n line breaks in frist textarea and  show him in the second textarea?

I've tried to use it directly within the variable \r \n is valid, but it reads the textarea\r \n is invalid and he is treated as plain text.

The final effect is shown in this figure:

[image]

Please help

Comment: We are Code junkies! Give us code!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this For New line.

```js
function output(v)
{
var str = v.replace(/(?:\\n)/g, '\n');
$("#txt2").val(str); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input:<br /><textarea id="txt1"  style="resize:none; width: 400px;height: 180px;" onKeyUp="output(this.value)"></textarea>
<br />
output:<br /><textarea id="txt2" style="resize:none; width: 400px;height: 180px;"  ></textarea>
```

Comment: What i need is to input \ r \ n from the first textarea and then output text that already line breaks  in the second textarea.

Comment: Okay Share Your R&D Code please

Comment: I try for a while, have solved this problem, thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay! That's Good News to ready to archive your target! @MC_Mtyh

Answer (score -1):

Hi @MC_Mtyh are you just trying to achieve a new line break using javascript...

```js
console.log("Hello \n this is a \n new line");
```

another option would be if you are using html

```
document.write("\n");
document.write("<br>");
```

Comment: Is beyond me why people down vote answer without any feedback this should not be allowed, who is benefiting from this absolutely nobody, not me nor the other participants, I can see why SO is getting a lot of bad rep, I can except a down vote if I knew why innocent till proven quilty not other way around